# CalendarView getDate() does not return time

Tags: android, date

I'm using the CalendarView to show a calendar, and load the current date&time. What I need is to get the current date and the time to use them in my activity. So, the time should be the current time, but the user is able to select another date.

This is how I have implemented:

```
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

AlertDialog diaBox = dateDialogBox();
diaBox.show();
final CalendarView calendarView = (CalendarView) diaBox.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
formatedDate = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
dateDialog.setTitle(formatedDate);
dateInMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        formatedDate = sdf.format(view.getDate());
        dateDialog.setTitle(formatedDate);
        dateInMillis = calendarView.getDate();
    }
});
```

When the dialog is prompted, it get's the date and time from **Calendar** and it does it right.
But when I select another date, it enters in **setOnDateChangeListener()** and here uses the **CalendarView** to get the date and time instead of **Calendar**. Because of this, I get the date correctly but the time appears this way 00:00:00.

What should I do to get the current time from CalendarView?

Comment: Create a `Calendar` object based on the `getDate()` return from `CalendarView`, then set the time on the `Calendar` object via `set()` calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CalendarView does not include time information (because it's just calendar). If you want to keep your time information and just apply selected dates, try to use Calender.set() method like this

```
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

AlertDialog diaBox = dateDialogBox();
diaBox.show();
final CalendarView calendarView = (CalendarView) diaBox.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);

final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
formatedDate = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
dateDialog.setTitle(formatedDate);
dateInMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        calendar.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
        long selectedDateInMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        formatedDate = sdf.format(selectedDateInMillis);
        dateDialog.setTitle(formatedDate);
        dateInMillis = selectedDateInMillis;
    }
});
```