# Get time from separate date and time fields?

Tags: android, datetime, kotlin

I'm creating a screen to schedule meetings in my app. I have a CalenderView which is being used to get the date and a TimePicker to select the time for the meeting. I want to store this data(date + time) in form of milliseconds since epoch so that I can do some math on it.

How do I combine date and time from the CalenderView and TimePicker and get milliseconds in kotlin?

Comment: Turn the day into milliseconds, then the time, then add them.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help:

> CalendarView does not include time information (because it's just calendar). If you want to keep your time information and just apply selected dates, try to use Calender.set() method like this

Original answer: 
[CalendarView getDate() does not return time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997985/calendarview-getdate-does-not-return-time)

You use: `calendar.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);` from inside a `OnDateChangeListener`

Then you can use the same approach for the `TimePicker` and setting the hours, minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 0):

**API LEVEL 26**

You just need to use the correct methods, instead of calling constructors. Use parse to create local date and local time objects, then pass the two objects to the method of LocalDateTime. After this convert it into milliseconds.

```
    LocalDate datePart = LocalDate.parse("2020-04-28");
    LocalTime timePart = LocalTime.parse("12:05:06");
    LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.of(datePart, timePart);
    System.out.println(dt.toString());
    long timeInMilliseconds = dt.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    System.out.println(timeInMilliseconds);
```

**API Level below 26**

Use a Calendar object:

```
        try {
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2020-04-28");
            Date startHour = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse("12:05");
            Date combinedDate = combine(date, startHour);
            System.out.println(combinedDate.toString());
            System.out.println("Milli Seconds: " + combinedDate.getTime());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    private static Date combine(Date date, Date time) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(time);
        int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
        return cal.getTime();
    }
```

**Happy Coding :)**

Comment: This works but its for API 26 and upward, In my project min sdk level is 23. What to do?